# Space overhead of in-place Radix sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, radix-sort

What is the space overhead of an in-place Radix sort when implemented recursively. I implemented an in-place Radix sort here, without recursion:

http://41j.com/blog/2015/03/in-place-radix-sort-ok-space-overhead/

I believe the way I have it implemented O(r^k) additional space will be required. Where r is the Radix and k is the number of digits. Am I right in thinking that a recursive solution would only require O(k) additional space?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems.  Citing a subtle one: `if ((v & (1 << bit)) > 0)` will fail if `int` are 32 bits and `bit` is `31`.  If `v` is negative, the expression will be non zero but not positive. This is not the only reason why negative numbers are not supported, your assumption on the high bit is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each recursive step sorts by another bit, the maximum recursion depth equals the sorting key's length in bits. So if your sorting key is k=32 bits long, you'll need to make a 32-levels recursion with a constant memory usage on each level.

Yes, you will need O(k) additional space for recursion stack.